# Sum of products which indice is not i an j

Tags: r, function, sum

I am implementing the following function in the R code:

[image: formula to be converted into code]

So far I used:

```
sig.TOM <- function(adj, sig.adj) {
out <- matrix(nrow = nrow(adj), ncol = ncol(adj))
  for (i in 1:nrow(adj)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(adj)) {
      out[i,j] <- abs(adj[i, j] + sum(sig.adj[i, -c(i, j)]*sig.adj[-c(i, j), i]))/(
        min(sum(sig.adj[-i, i]), sum(sig.adj[-j, j])) + 1 - abs(adj[i,j]))
    }
  }
  return(out)
}
```

where ~a is the following mock matrix:

```
sig.adj <- structure(c(1, -0.418913311940584, 1, 0.947013383275973, -1, 
-0.418913311940584, 1, -0.207962861914701, 0.584386281408348, 
-0.687223049826016, 1, -0.207962861914701, 1, 0.763551721347657, 
-0.0327147711077901, 0.947013383275973, 0.584386281408348, 0.763551721347657, 
1, 0.284466543760789, -1, -0.687223049826016, -0.0327147711077901, 
0.284466543760789, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

and `adj <- abs(sig.adj)`, where adj in the formula is described as a and sig.adj as ~a.

But the result is not symmetric as expected so I must have implemented it wrong, I have doubts on the summation part.

How can that sum of products of values when the indices are not i or j be implemented?

---

The proposed solutions:

```
spec.mult1 <- function(A,B) {
  rA <- nrow(A); cB <- ncol(B)
  C <- A %*% B
  for (i in 1:rA) for (j in 1:cB) 
    C[i,j] <- C[i,j] - A[i,i]*B[i,j] - A[i,j]*B[j,j] + ifelse(i==j, A[i,i]*B[j,j], 0) 
  C
}

spec.mult2 <- function(A) {
  dA.A <- diag(A)*A
  crossprod(A) - dA.A - t(dA.A) + diag(diag(A)^2)
}

spec.mult3 <- function(A,B) {
  rA <- nrow(A); cB <- ncol(B)
  C <- A %*% B
  for (i in 1:rA) for (j in 1:cB) 
    C[i,j] <- C[i,j] - A[i,i]*B[i,j] - A[i,j]*B[j,j] 
  C
}

spec.mult4 <- function(A) {
  dA.A <- diag(A)*A
  crossprod(A) - dA.A - t(dA.A)
}

spec.mult5 <- function(sig.adj) {
  nr <- nrow(sig.adj); nc <- ncol(sig.adj)
  C <- matrix(NA, nr, nc)
  for (i in 1:nr) for (j in 1:nc) 
    C[i,j] <- sum(sig.adj[i, -c(i, j)]*sig.adj[-c(i, j), j])
  C
}
```

Comparing the results of each function :

```
all(res1 == res2)
[1] TRUE
> all(res1 == res3)
[1] FALSE
> all(res1 == res4)
[1] FALSE
> all(res1 == res5)
[1] FALSE
> all(res2 == res3)
[1] FALSE
> all(res2 == res4)
[1] FALSE
> all(res2 == res5)
[1] FALSE
> all(res3 == res4)
[1] TRUE
> all(res3 == res5)
[1] FALSE
> all(res4 == res5)
[1] FALSE
```

Results that, spec.mult1 == spec.mult2 and spec.mult3 == spec.mult4 but spec.mult5 (the one I understand, and hope it is correct) doesn't appear

Comment: Why are you calculating `... - abs(adj[i,j])` when `adj <- abs(sig.mat)`?

Comment: Good point @jogo I was blindly implementing the function.

Comment: Thanks @jogo, one answer tells me what is wrong in my formula, and the other calculates the formula without explaining what is made. (My formula corrected per Vandenman and your formula differ) And neither of them explains how to write the "sum of products of values when the indices are not i or j". Thus I am not accepting neither of them even if they were helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solutions. I think now I learned how to do it, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for comparing the results of the different functions. The difference `spec.mult5(sig.adj) - spec.mult4(sig.adj)`is surprizing for me. all other is clear. BTW: is is not a good idea to compare floating point numbers per `==` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: I was wrong in thinking about omitted indicies (how they work in R). I edited my answer. Now all functions give the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C_{ij} = \sum_{u} a_{iu} b_{uj})$ is a normal matrix multiplication. So you can get $\sum_{u \ne i,j} a_{iu} b_{uj}$ by correcting the result of a matrix multiplication (i.e. subtracting the unwanted parts of the sum).
Take care of the fact that in the case of `i==j` only one part of $\sum_{u} a_{iu} b_{uj})$ has to be neglected.

something about omitted indicies:

```
A <- matrix(c(1:4, 2,5:7, 3,6,8:9, 4,7,9,10), 4,4)
A[1, -c(1,1)]
```

The element is omitted only once.

The part of the formula beside the special matrix multiplication is clear:

```
sig.TOM <- function(sig.adj) {
  adj <- abs(sig.adj)
  k <- colSums(adj) - abs(diag(adj))
  abs(adj + spec.mult(sig.adj, sig.adj)) / (outer(k,k, pmin) +1 - abs(adj))
}
sig.TOM(sig.adj)
```

(or `spec.mult(sig.adj)` for a one-argument variant of the special matrix multiplication, see below)
p.s.: I copied the part `... +1 - abs(adj)` from your question because I don't know if you want `... +1 - adj` or `... +1 - sig.adj`

Here are five variants of the special matrix multiplication:

```
A <- matrix(c(1:4, 2,5:7, 3,6,8:9, 4,7,9,10), 4,4)
A[1, -c(1,1)]

spec.mult1 <- function(A,B) {
  rA <- nrow(A); cB <- ncol(B)
  C <- A %*% B
  for (i in 1:rA) for (j in 1:cB) 
    C[i,j] <- C[i,j] - A[i,i]*B[i,j] - A[i,j]*B[j,j] + ifelse(i==j, A[i,i]*B[j,j], 0) 
  C
}

spec.mult2 <- function(A) {
  dA.A <- diag(A)*A
  crossprod(A) - dA.A - t(dA.A) + diag(diag(A)^2)
}

spec.mult3 <- function(A,B) {
  rA <- nrow(A); cB <- ncol(B)
  C <- A %*% B
  for (i in 1:rA) for (j in 1:cB) 
    C[i,j] <- C[i,j] - A[i,i]*B[i,j] - A[i,j]*B[j,j] 
  for (i in 1:rA) C[i,i] <- C[i,i] + A[i,i]*B[i,i]
  C
}

spec.mult4 <- function(A) {
  dA <- diag(A)
  dA.A <- dA*A
  crossprod(A) - dA.A - t(dA.A) + diag(dA^2)
}

spec.mult5 <- function(sig.adj) {
  nr <- nrow(sig.adj); nc <- ncol(sig.adj)
  C <- matrix(NA, nr, nc)
  for (i in 1:nr) for (j in 1:nc) 
    C[i,j] <- sum(sig.adj[i, -c(i, j)]*sig.adj[-c(i, j), j])
  C
}

spec.mult1(A, A) - spec.mult5(A) 
spec.mult2(A) - spec.mult5(A)
spec.mult3(A, A) - spec.mult5(A) 
spec.mult4(A) - spec.mult5(A)
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I don't understand the spec.mult function, how are they equivalent? How could I calculate the sum of the absolute product of a_iu a_uj with it?

Comment: yes, they are equivalent, but I don't understand why. There is another formula with a slightly different approach, see the equation 4 of the [report](https://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/TechnicalReports/signedTOM.pdf) I am trying to use, which I would like to implement too

Comment: I would prefer to understand how to do the $\sum_{u \ne i,j} a_{iu} a_{uj}$ or $\sum_{u \ne i,j} \abs(a_{iu} a_{uj})$. And Whatever it is spec.mult I don't understand it, or how to tweak it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you indexed incorrectly in the sum over `u!=i, j`. The part

`sum(sig.adj[i, -c(i, j)]*sig.adj[-c(i, j), i])`

should be

`sum(sig.adj[i, -c(i, j)]*sig.adj[-c(i, j), j])`

With your example the output is then a symmetric matrix for me.